# How to show records filtered by specific category

Tags: laravel, list, categories

[image: this is my blade file]
[image: this is my controller]

how can I list a musician of a certain category in my blade file with an if?

Comment: in the musician table there is the cateogry_id as a field. can I specify an if like: if category_id == 10 then list the musicians?

Comment: Please post the actual code within code blocks in the question instead of images. When you attach images it becomes uninteresting to write the entire code block with suggested modifications. Hence please remove the images and post the actual code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to list or show musicians of a particular category on the view then you can filter the musicians in the controller method and then send the filtered data to view

```php
public function group()
{
    return view('pages.group', [
        'musicians' => Musician::where('category_id', 10)->get()
    ]);
}
```

And then in blade view

```
@foreach($musicians as $musician)
    <p>{{ $musician->musician_name }} {{ $musician->musician_surname }}</p>
@endforeach
```

> it works thanks. but if I wanted to print on one line the musicians of the category with id 10 and on another line the musicians of the category with id 40? always on the same blade file

```php
public function group()
{
    return view('musicians', [
        'categories' => Musician::get()->groupBy(function($item) {
            return $item->category_id;
        })
    ]);
}
```

```
@foreach($categories as $catetory)
    @foreach($category as $key => $musician)
        <p>{{ $musician->musician_name }} {{ $musician->musician_surname }}</p>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: it works thanks. but if I wanted to print on one line the musicians of the category with id 10 and on another line the musicians of the category with id 40? always on the same blade file

Comment: @AntonioPalermo Have updated the answer in response to your above comment. Have a look and let me know it thats what you meant